# libjpeg error 117 <Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment> from output_message

Tags: android, image, libjpeg

Since some point i get this error. On API21- all works file, on API24 all ok, API29+ broken, didn't tested other, may be someone know what happened or changed?

Here simple is code:

```
    @Nullable
    Bitmap getImage() {
        if (!isMediaFileExist()) return null;
        MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        try {
            mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(getMediaFile().getFullPath());
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            return null;
        }
        byte[] imageByte = mediaMetadataRetriever.getEmbeddedPicture();     #MIN API 8
        if (imageByte == null) return null;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageByte, 0, imageByte.length);
    }
```

Source function bigger, but this cuted part isn't working too.

Bitmap assigns to ImageView by standard way.

In result I see some part of picture and grey background.

That has happened with all mp3. On API21 still all looks good.

I've tried for test to do `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageByte, 0, imageByte.length-16384);` for example and have same part of image with grey background. Looks like lib encounter error. But on PC, in photoShop, Paint and other picture looks good. Headers in HEX editor looks good to.

Inside MP3 cover are standard JPEG, 53Kb, about 300x300 px, but size doesn't matter I think, it happened with all mp3

Answer (score 1):

Didn't find solution for `MediaMetadataRetriever`
moved to https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever

works fine. Only one problem +16Mb of apk